# Tkinter Toplevel Widget

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def WhoisWin():

win1 = Toplevel()
win1.title("Whois")
win1.config(bg="black")
win1.geometry("300x300")
win1.resizable(0,0)

text = Text()
text1 = Text()

text1.config(width=15, height=1)
text1.config(bg="black", fg="white")
text1.pack()

def button1():
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.connect(("com.whois-servers.net", 43))
            s.send(text1.get("1.0", END) + "\r\n")
            response = ''
            while True:
                a = s.recv(4096)
                response += a
                if a == '':
                   break
            s.close()
            text.insert(END, response)

def clear():
        text.delete("1.0", END)  
        text1.delete("1.0", END)       

frame = Frame(win1)
frame.config(bg="black")
frame.pack(pady=10, padx=5)

b = Button(frame, text="Enter", width=10, height=2, command=button1)
b.config(fg="white", bg="black")
b.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5)

c = Button(frame, text="Clear", width=10, height=2, command=clear)
c.config(fg="white", bg="black")
c.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(win1)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
text.config(width=35, height=15, bg="black", fg="white")
text.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
scrollbar.config(command=text.yview)
text.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
```

This is just a child window that will popup when you click on the menu, I don't get any errors, but Text and Tex1 is not visible on the child window, but when I run this code on its own root window it works just find, maybe the ident is messed up or something? Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provide a parent for `text` or `text1`. When you call `Text()` you need to give it an argument like `Text(win1)` or `Text(frame)` so that Tkinter knows what to pack the Text widget on.

Comment: to be pedantic, the first argument doesn't tell Tkinter "what to pack the text widget on". Rather, it defines the parent of the widget. A side effect  is that `grid`, `pack` and `place` by default put widgets in their parents.